# How does PHP access smarty template textbox inputs?

Tags: php, input, smarty

I am really new to PHP and smarty template (started learning yesterday) and now I have to do a project using them.

Could somebody please tell me if in a tpl file I have a textbox for user to input something, how do I pass that input to php file to process? Probably pretty dumb question to you all, but I have been only used .NET

There's one other thing, what is PHP5? The project manager said I could only used it.

Thanks.

Comment: Php5 is the latest version of php (5.4.12 is the actual current release version).

Answer (score 0):

If you're that new to it, you'll want to find an introductory tutorial or two to get the "feel" of PHP, but to give you a few pointers:

- PHP is the server-side language which will process all the data in your application
- "PHP5" just means "PHP, version 5"; for a while, people were still writing and maintaining code for PHP 4, because there were some major changes between the two versions, but that's not really been relevant for some time now (PHP 4 hasn't been supported since the end of 2007)
- Smarty is a templating language built on top of PHP, used for generating the HTML that actually gets sent to the browser
- An HTML form (outside ASP.net, which has its own unique way of dealing with things) submits data to whatever page you put in the `action="..."` attribute of the `<form>` tag. That page can then be a PHP (or Ruby, Python, etc) script which looks at the data and does appropriate things with it.

Hope that leads you in the right direction. Happy coding! :)